# SQL Server 2005 - How do I do a rolling calculation on 2 results within the same column in a result-set?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

For example, I have a table with the following columns:

```
EXTRACT_DATE, TABLE_NAME, NUMBER_ROWS, DATA_SIZE.
```

The `DATA_SIZE` column is a `bigint` data type and I'm looking to subtract one value from another to get the size difference in a separate column. The maximum row count for the result-set is 52 rows and this has to be done for each set of two rows.

Can someone help me with the code I should use? Let me know if you need any more info.

Sample data:

```
EXTRACT_DATE    TABLE_NAME  NUMBER_ROWS DATA_SIZE
2014-07-17      FGDISD      1           24576
2014-07-17      FFIDXH      1           24576
2014-07-17      FFIIRH      37          28672
```

There are multiple extracts for each table, each going back a week.

Expected output

```
EXTRACT_DATE    TABLE_NAME  NUMBER_ROWS DATA_SIZE   SIZE_DIFF   
2017-07-15      FGLEDG      141673883   76221730816 184553472   
2017-07-08      FGLEDG      141323505   76037177344 184549376
2017-07-01      FGLEDG      140971673   75852627968 184549376
```

Comment: Edit your question to include sample data, expected output and what you have tried so far

Comment: You also might want to consider upgrading your database. 2005 is no longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no choice in what version to be using otherwise I'd definitely be using a later version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `EXTRACT_DATE` is unique, and it's the column you use to order your result set by, you can probably do something like this:

```
SELECT  EXTRACT_DATE, 
        TABLE_NAME, 
        NUMBER_ROWS, 
        DATA_SIZE,
        DATA_SIZE - 
        ISNULL((
            SELECT TOP 1 DATA_SIZE
            FROM TableName as t1
            WHERE t1.TABLE_NAME = t0.TABLE_NAME
            AND t1.EXTRACT_DATE < t0.EXTRACT_DATE
            ORDER BY EXTRACT_DATE DESC
        ), 0) As DATA_SIZE_DIFF
FROM TableName as t0
```

If you would have provided sample data as DDL+DML as well as desired results, I would be able to test my answer.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to get the expected results, but I have provided sample data/expected results for you to test it with now. I've also provided my solution as well, which is highly complicated for something which would seem so simple.

Comment: I fail to see the connection between your sample data and desired results. Also, when providing sample data, it's best to provide it as DDL+DML (Create table and Insert statements).

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to resolve my question using two temporary tables and using the values in each of them to calculate the size difference. I wouldn't say it's the best way of doing this however it seems to work for what I'm wanting to do. If there's a simpler way of doing this, I still would love to see it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableGrowthReport]
@NoOWeeks int,
@TableName varchar(15)

AS
--Declares & sets variables
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
DECLARE @CalcDate DATETIME

SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
SET @CalcDate = DATEADD(ww, @NoOWeeks, @CurrentDate)

CREATE TABLE #Data 
(
    RowNo int,
    EXTRACT_DATE varchar(19),
    TABLE_NAME varchar(128),
    NUMBER_ROWS bigint,
    DATA_SIZE bigint,
    DATA_SIZE2 bigint,
);

CREATE TABLE #Data2 
(
    RowNo int,
    DATA_SIZE2 bigint
);

INSERT INTO #Data 
    (RowNo,
    EXTRACT_DATE,
    TABLE_NAME,
    NUMBER_ROWS,
    DATA_SIZE,
    DATA_SIZE2)
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT_DATE desc) as RowNo,
         EXTRACT_DATE,
         TABLE_NAME,
         NUMBER_ROWS,
         DATA_SIZE,
         NULL
    FROM M3Rows_PF
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND EXTRACT_DATE > 
            (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), @CalcDate, 20));

INSERT INTO #Data2 
    (RowNo,
    DATA_SIZE2)
        SELECT 
            RowNo,
            DATA_SIZE
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT_DATE desc) - 1 as RowNo,
                EXTRACT_DATE,
                TABLE_NAME,
                NUMBER_ROWS,
                DATA_SIZE
                FROM M3Rows_PF
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                    AND EXTRACT_DATE > 
                        (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), @CalcDate, 20))
                        )r
                        WHERE rowno > 0;

UPDATE a 
SET DATA_SIZE2 = b.DATA_SIZE2
FROM #Data a
JOIN #Data2 b ON a.RowNo = b.RowNo
WHERE a.RowNo = b.RowNo

SELECT  
    RowNo,
    EXTRACT_DATE,
    TABLE_NAME,
    NUMBER_ROWS,
    DATA_SIZE,
    DATA_SIZE2,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATA_SIZE > 0 AND DATA_SIZE < 10000000
            THEN LEFT(DATA_SIZE * 1.0 / 10000, 4) + 'kb' 
        WHEN DATA_SIZE >= 10000000 AND DATA_SIZE < 1000000000
            THEN LEFT(DATA_SIZE * 1.0 / 1000000, 5)  + 'mb'
        ELSE 
            LEFT(DATA_SIZE * 1.0 / 1000000000, 5) + 'gb' END AS DATA_SIZECONV,
    DATA_SIZE - DATA_SIZE2 AS SIZE_DIFF,
    LEFT((DATA_SIZE - DATA_SIZE2) * 1.0 / 1000000, 5) AS SIZE_DIFFmb
FROM #data
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
    AND EXTRACT_DATE > 
        (SELECT 
            CONVERT(varchar(10), @CalcDate, 20)
        )   

DROP TABLE #Data
DROP TABLE #Data2
```